# Switch between Workbooks, Loop through sheets and copy values

Tags: vba

I'm stuck, I am trying to write the macro, we have 2 files;
ORG - empty file that I am running the macro from
NOT_ORG - sheets with some data
I want to loop through sheets in NOT_Org, check if this sheet name is in array, if so, create a new sheet in ORG file, paste the value from NOT_ORG, and loop over next sheets from NOT_ORG to check the same. Below code I wrote so far, I am getting confused how to comfortable switch between Workbooks, as I am getting errors - either when I am setting WB2 and second issue is within For each loop. Could someone point me to the right direction, how to switch between these workbooks within this for each loop?

```
Sub Test1()

  Dim WshtNames As Variant
  Dim WshtNameCrnt As Variant
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim os As Worksheet
  Dim x As String
  Dim WB1 As Workbook
  Dim WB2 As Workbook
  Set WB1 = ActiveWorkbook
  Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\NOT_ORG.xlsx")

  ' loop through sheets in file that i just open (wb2), check if sheet name is in array below, 
  ' copy A1 value & assign to a variable sheet name that i am copying from, with new prefix 
  ' _new / open "org file" - that I am running macro from - create a new sheet and assign this 
  ' sheet name, paste the value. And do the same for each sheet if this sheet name is in list.
  '
  WshtNames = Array("2", "3")

  For Each WshtNameCrnt In WshtNames
    With Worksheets(WshtNameCrnt).Activate
      Range("A1").Select
      Selection.Copy
      Sheets.Add.Name = WshtNameCrnt & "_new"
      ' -> S
      
      'x = ActiveSheet.Name
      '#MsgBox (x)
      ActiveSheet.Paste
          
    End With
  Next WshtNameCrnt

End Sub
```

Thanks
eM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, replace:

```
For Each WshtNameCrnt In WshtNames
    With Worksheets(WshtNameCrnt).Activate
      Range("A1").Select
      Selection.Copy
      Sheets.Add.Name = WshtNameCrnt & "_new"
      ' -> S
      
      'x = ActiveSheet.Name
      '#MsgBox (x)
      ActiveSheet.Paste
          
    End With
  Next WshtNameCrnt
```

with:

```
  For Each WshtNameCrnt In WshtNames
    WB1.Sheets.Add.Name = WshtNameCrnt & "_new"
    WB2.Worksheets(WshtNameCrnt).Range("A1").Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
  Next WshtNameCrnt
```

In order to work, two sheets named as "1" and "2" (not their index) should exist in `WB2`.

Activating, selecting only consumes Excel resources, making the code slower and not bringing any benefit...

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, that works.
I am trying to modify the range I am copying - starting from A7, and copying all rows till last (last row might change from sheet to sheet) - and below code works for sheet 2, but sheet 3 is empty and I am getting error : Application-defined or object-definied error - any ideas why is that?

WshtNames = Array("2", "3")
For Each WshtNameCrnt In WshtNames
WB1.Sheets.Add.Name = WshtNameCrnt & "_new"
WB2.Worksheets(WshtNameCrnt).Range("A7", Range("A7").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
Next WshtNameCrnt

Thanks,
eM

Comment: @eM_Sk You should declare a new variable (`Dim lastRow As Long`) and calculate it prior to the problematic code line. Then check the value of `lastRow` and copy the range only if it is greater the 8. `lastRow = Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row`. `If lastRow >=8 Then` and copy the range since it exists...